# Did Jewish Ethiopians only discover the destruction of the Second Temple when they moved to Israel?

Tags: history, jews

[Here's](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/we-did-not-know-how-ethiopian-jews-discovered-the-second-temple-was-gone/) a supposed first-person account saying that she (an Ethiopian Jew) only found out about the destruction of the Second temple when she moved to Israel.

[Here's](http://www.aish.com/h/9av/aas/The_Heart_Rending_Cry.html) another account.

But Ethiopia wasn't that far away from the rest of the world, and has many adherents to post-Biblical religions. Many traveling Jews passed through it in the late Middle Ages and early Modern age.

Was it really true that Ethiopian Jews were ignorant of the destruction of the Second Temple?

Comment: The question in the title is contradicted by the second account. Is your question "Do many Jewish Ethiopians wrongly believe the Second Temple is intact?" The discussion of travellers in the Middle Ages seems a distraction.

Comment: \[I am nervous that a disposable account asking about Jews is the tip of an anti-semetic iceberg, but our Be Nice rules include assuming good faith, and there is evidence that [Ethiopian Judaism teachings](https://www.breakingisraelnews.com/80005/ethiopian-judaism-nearly-identical-second-temple-practice/) differ from some others, so I am prepared to provisionally accept it as genuine.\]

Comment: @Oddthinking "Our children came home yesterday and told us that their teacher taught them that the Temple in Jerusalem no longer exists. Who would tell them such a thing?" He looked at me in anger.

Comment: Yes, that directly answers the question in the title. It clearly demonstrates some Jewish Ethiopians learned about the Second Temple no longer existing without travelling to Israel (and independent of travellers from the late Middle Ages and early Modern age). So what is the real question?